# CPU Die when fan speed is slow

Tags: macbook-pro, cpu, temperature

I recently bought a second hand MBP early 2013 15' quad core. Everything seems fine so far except 2 cpu died events I experienced.

The first one is happened last week when I exported a 2 minutes iMovie's video and today when I'm browsing a news website with heavy ads and ad video inside it.

The macbook suddenly fade to black and shutdown for few minutes, and this was happened suddenly and the fan was running at normal speed / slow. I got a iStat warning before it, that said CPU load over 50% for 10 seconds but the fan speed didn't increase.

This cpu die is not always happen. I'm still able to export iMovie's video and I open the same website daily, but I'm just worry about it.

Is it something normal? Can you guys give me a clue what is happened? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Wow, I have never heard of this, I hope someone can help you.  Any way you can return your purchase? There is an app called smcFanSupport that will give you the speed of your fans. But I wouldn't think a spike of less that a second would cause a heat issue.

Comment: @jmh I've never experienced this too with all of my macs I ever have before. This is my first time purchasing a second hand macbook because my previous mbp got broken. This mbp is running well and its performance meets my expectation, but this issue makes me worry. And yes I still have a chance to return the purchase

Comment: Sure wish I knew the answer.  Be patient and maybe someone will read it who knows the answer.